# menu sidebar didn't expand it self again in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, sidebar

I have a menu on my sidebar as shown below

I have this code

```
<ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
        <li><a href="/ES/"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-star"></span><span class="sidebar-title">الرئيسية</span></a> </li>

        <li><a class="accordion-toggle menu-open" href="#resources"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-settings"></span><span class="sidebar-title">الخدمــــات</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="resources" class="nav sub-nav">
                <li><a href="/ES/Pages/ServiceItems/ServicesList.aspx"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-edit"></span>طلب خدمة جديدة</a></li>

                <li><a href="/ES/Pages/ServiceItems/ServicesInbox.aspx"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-message_new"></span>وارد </a></li>
                <li><a href="/ES/Pages/ServiceItems/ServicesOutbox.aspx"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-book"></span>الصادر </a></li>
                <li><a href="/ES/Pages/ServiceItems/MyServices.aspx"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-book"></span>خدماتي </a></li>


                <li class="active"><a class="menu-open" href="/ES/Pages/ServiceItems/OverAllSearch.aspx"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search"></span>البحث العام </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
```

the a tag contain class "accordion-toggle menu-open " on the page load

after I click on the menu to collapse it 
the a tag contain class "accordion-toggle" then when I try to expand my menu again it display it less than 1 sec. and hide it again .
sadly this behavior  happen in single one page not all of them

Comment: do you get a post back when you click the accordion